# Where is the default installation folder of microsoft enterprise library?

Tags: enterprise-library-5

I wanted to install Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 on my pc but a message told me it has been installed already.Now I want to know where is the default installation folder of enterprise library?

Comment: I Download and ran FoderChangesView tool to monitor folder changes  after clicking repaire button in Enterprise library 5 Entry of Add/remove programs of windows .

Answer (score 0):

I Download and ran FoderChangesView tool to monitor folder changes  after clicking repair button in Enterprise library 5 Entry of Add/remove programs of windows .

I led to 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft patterns & practices\Enterprise Library 5.0
  on which there was a batch file named Install Instrumentation (InstallServices.bat)
by viewing the file I found out the path .it was :

%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\